# Como interactuar con un script bash desde el navegaor

Tags: php, bash, script

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script bash desde el navegador usando php.

Mi script es algo como este

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Agregagar nueva cuenta de Google drive"
drive init
```

Al ejecutarlo desde la consola me arroja esto:

```
Visit this URL to get an authorization code
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=36478790962074-7rrlnuanmamgg1i4feed12dpuq871bvd.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&state=2019-07-02+15%3A45%3A02.284515677+%2B0230+CEST2596996162
Paste the authorization code:
```

La url la copio y la abro desde el navegador para ingresar el código de autorización en el script que esta a la espera.

**Mi problema al ejecutar este script en el navegador es que NO QUEDA A LA ESPERA**

en php tengo este archivo:

```
<?php 

$k = system('/var/www/html/acordeon/./ss.sh 2>&1 1> /dev/null', $retval);
echo $K;

?>
```

Pero el script no queda a la espera de insertar el ningún dato.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada debes tener instalado el CGI de php para poder ejecutar y ver php en el navegador directamente. 
Adicionalmente, ya que este tema puede presentar algunos problemas de seguridad, te recomendaría leer algo de documentación al respecto.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/install.unix.commandline.php

Dicho esto, si tienes instalado php-cgi y configurado el intérprete de php para ejecutar tu código adecuadamente, sería así. (En caso de faltarte esta configuración o no funcionar, avisa y edito con mas info)

1º Creas un archivo PHP con la siguiente estructura

```php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $text=shell_exec("./check 2>&1");
    echo $text;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Justo al mismo nivel donde tienes ese archivo php, creas otro archivo de tipo `SH`, podrías poner la extensión del archvio "miScript.sh" o simplemente "miScript" y al comienzo del archivo defines el tipo quedando algo así

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Agregagar nueva cuenta de Google drive"
```

Lo único que quedaría sería adaptar la ruta a tu script correctamente, en mi caso lo hice en la misma carpeta.

*Tener en cuenta que `shell_exec()` y `exec()` no pueden ejecutar scripts interactivos.*

**Por último, mencionar que podrías considerar no usar un bash para realizar una secuencia de eventos, sino utilizar los comandos uno a uno haciendo uso de `exeCmd()`. 
De esta manera, puedes manejar el retorno y mantener toda la lógica de errores en PHP y no dividirlo en PHP y Bash.**

Saludos!

PD: Es posible que tu archivo del script requiera permisos de ejecución :)

Comment: Gracias por responder. El código se ejecuta sin problemas pero el inconveniente que hay es que PHP no puede interpretar las indicaciones de BASH, por ejemplo: `read -p "INGRESAR TEXTO: " TEXT` esta linea hace una "pausa" en la ejecución del script bash y pide que se inserte un texto, cuando se le ingresa el texto prosigue con la ejecución el scrip, pero php solo ejecuta texto plano y no da ninguna opción para la inserción de dicho texto hacia el script bash. Prácticamente no hay una interacción de php con bash.

Comment: Entiendo, te dejo este enlace de referencia que quizás te ayude a entender como gestionar interacción con php y bash. Si te cuesta el inglés coméntame y agrego el contenido explicándolo aquí en castellano complementando la respuesta inicial. Básicamente, no puedes hacer uso de una consola interactiva con  ```shell_exec()``` ni ```exec()``` . Esto es algo más complejo. Y la verdad, sentí la misma conclusión que esta respuesta ¿Realmente necesitas bash? ¿Porque no lo haces con php directo?.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060011/executing-bash-script-with-php-and-input-commands